# Automatic plotting of graphs from different sheet

Tags: vba, graph

I am programming an excel application that takes info from a Tables Sheet ( that it is also programmed and the length and position of each table can change) and generate a graphic for each table in other sheet, called Estimation Sheet, when a button is press.

I managed to do this task for the first graphich (corresponding to first table) but when I try to use the same method for the second...it doesn't work. This is the method used to draw the first graphic:

```
    Public Sub generateGraphicsC(RowResistiveC As Integer)

       Dim FirstRow As Integer, FirstColumn As Integer, LastRow As Integer, LastColumn As Integer,         GraphLocation As Integer
       Dim XelementsC As Integer, Yelements As Integer

       Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
       Dim rngChtData As Range
       Dim rngChtXVal As Range
       Dim i As Integer


       Dim WSD As Worksheet
       Set WSD = Worksheets(2)     'Data source

       Dim CSD As Worksheet
       Set CSD = Worksheets(3)     'ChartOutput

       'Dim chrt As ChartObject
       'Dim cw As Long
       'Dim rh As Long

       ' get the current charts so proper overwriting can happen Dim chtObjs As ChartObjects
       Set chtObjs = CSD.ChartObjects
       WSD.AutoFilterMode = False       ' Turn off autofilter mode
       'Dim finalRow As Long            ' Find the last row with data
       'finalRow = WSD.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


       FirstRow = RowResistiveC
       FirstColumn = 5

       XelementsC = countXelementsC(FirstRow - 1, FirstColumn)                  'Count the x         Elements (amperes)
       Yelements = countYelements(FirstRow)                                      'Count the y Elements (Combinations)

       LastRow = FirstRow + Yelements - 1                                      'The last row and column I will read
       LastColumn = FirstColumn + XelementsC - 1

       '---------------------DRAW THE GRAPHIC----------------------------------------------'

       ' Delete any previous existing chart
        'Dim chtObj As ChartObject

       ' define the x axis values
       WSD.Activate
       Set rngChtXVal = WSD.Range(Cells(FirstRow - 1, FirstColumn), Cells(FirstRow - 1, LastColumn))

       ' add the chart
          Charts.Add

          With ActiveChart
          ' make a XY chart
             .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
             ' remove extra series
             Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
                .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
             Loop

             .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Estimation Sheets"
          End With

          '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
          With ActiveChart
             .HasTitle = True
             .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Factor C"

             'To Interpolate between the ungiven values
             .DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated


              'TITLE STYLE
             .ChartTitle.AutoScaleFont = False
             With .ChartTitle.Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Size = 14
                .Strikethrough = False
                        .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Background = xlAutomatic
             End With

             'AXIS STYLE-----------------------------------------------------------------------

             .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.AutoScaleFont = False
             With .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .FontStyle = "Regular"
                .Size = 10
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Background = xlAutomatic
             With Selection.Border
                .ColorIndex = 15
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With


             End With
             .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.AutoScaleFont = False
             With .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .FontStyle = "Regular"
                .Size = 8
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Background = xlAutomatic
             End With

          End With
          '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
          ' HEIGHT; WIDTH AND POSITION

          GraphLocation = CSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 3

          Dim RngToCover As Range
          Set RngToCover = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(GraphLocation, 2), Cells(GraphLocation + 20, 11))
          With ActiveChart.Parent
             .Height = RngToCover.Height ' resize
             .Width = RngToCover.Width   ' resize
             .Top = RngToCover.Top       ' reposition
             .Left = RngToCover.Left     ' reposition
          End With

       ' for each row in the sheet
       For i = FirstRow To LastRow
          Dim chartName As String
          ' define chart data range for the row (record)
           Set rngChtData = WSD.Range(WSD.Cells(i, FirstColumn), WSD.Cells(i, LastColumn))

          'To get the serie name that I´m going to add to the graph
          Dim serieName As String
          Dim varItemName As Variant
          WSD.Activate
          varItemName = WSD.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))
          serieName = CStr(varItemName(1, 1) + " " + varItemName(1, 2) + " " + varItemName(1, 3) + " " + varItemName(1, 4))

          ' add series from selected range, column by column

             CSD.ChartObjects.Select


            With ActiveChart
                With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Values = rngChtData
                .XValues = rngChtXVal
                .Name = serieName
            End With
            End With

        Next i

         'We let as last view the page with all the info
         CSD.Select


    End Sub
```

I am calling this Sub from other one. The next step will be calling a similar method (exactly the same but other starting point to get the data and some different format properties)for other kind of table and graphic:

```
    Public Sub printGraphics()

       Modul4.ClearGraphs

       Modul4.generateGraphicsC (RowResistiveC)

       Modul4.generateGraphicsT (RowResistiveT)

    End Sub
```

And so on. CountXelements and Yelements counts the number of elements from the Tables Sheet and RowResistiveC, for example, keeps the position of the table.

GenerateGraphicsC works but generateGraphicsT (exactly the same) crush in the line:

`With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries`

Whit error 91 ( I have a german version of excel at work but it's something like variable object or bloque object not given).

Comment: I'm quite sure that the error comes from here:

CSD.ChartObjects.Select

I think for the first time it's ok because there is only one object, but for the second time I'm not specifying with chart I'm selecting.

I did a test, adding the second graph without having add the first one and it works fine. 

How could I solve this? I try replacing that sentence: .ChartObjects(1).Chart

But It doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected the error came from :

`CSD.ChartObjects.Select`

That works in my solution for the first graph since I'm selecting the single graphic on the sheet, but when I add more it doesn´t.

I just changed that line for:

`CSD.ChartObjects(1).Activate`

and so on. It works perfectly. I also had to make some adjusments to avoid all the graphs being plotted over the previous one, but it works nice.